# change the color of the range slider based on the value

Tags: angular

I have a range slider and I need to change the color of the slider from red to green as the value increases. I tried with below code but it's not working. based on the value of the `masterRangeslider` color should change. Thanks in advance.

```js
masterRangeslider:Number;
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <input name="range" type="range" class="range-slider__range" [(ngModel)]="masterRangeslider" [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'linear-gradient(90deg, hsl('+ (10 * masterRangeslider +', 90%, 50%) '+ (10 * masterRangeslider +'%, #d7dcdf 0%)'  }" min="0" max="10">
     <div class="rating" [ngStyle]="{ 'left': ((10 * masterRangeslider - 3) + '%' }">{{masterRangeslider}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to close the braces in ngStyle (10* masterRangeslider )<---

Just use the below code.

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <input name="range" type="range" class="range-slider__range" [(ngModel)]="masterRangeslider" [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'linear-gradient(90deg, hsl('+ (10 * masterRangeslider) +', 90%, 50%) '+ (10 * masterRangeslider) +'%, #d7dcdf 0%)'  }" min="0" max="10">
     <div class="rating" [ngStyle]="{ 'left': ((10 * masterRangeslider - 3) + '%' }">{{masterRangeslider}}</div>
</div>
```